# MySQL groovy syntax

Tags: mysql, groovy

```
import groovy.sql.Sql

mysqlSql = Sql.newInstance(

    System.getenv("FRS_MYSQL_URL"),
    System.getenv("FRS_MYSQL_USERNAME"),
    System.getenv("FRS_MYSQL_PW"),
    System.getenv("MYSQL_DRIVER_NAME")
)

mysqlSql.connection.autoCommit = false;

crg_work_sync =
        """
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/local/apps/msadeploy/output/clarifi/ingestion/output/cash_flow_scores.csv' INTO TABLE crg_work.cash_flow_scores
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LINES TERMINATED BY '\\n';

LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/local/apps/msadeploy/output/clarifi/ingestion/output/eqi_500_scores.csv' INTO TABLE crg_work.eqi_500_scores
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LINES TERMINATED BY '\\n';

LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/local/apps/msadeploy/output/clarifi/ingestion/output/eqi_4000_scores.csv' INTO TABLE crg_work.eqi_4000_scores
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LINES TERMINATED BY '\\n';

LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/local/apps/msadeploy/output/clarifi/ingestion/output/eqi_basic_scores.csv' INTO TABLE crg_work.eqi_basic_scores
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LINES TERMINATED BY '\\n';

LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/local/apps/msadeploy/output/clarifi/ingestion/output/eqi_company.csv' INTO TABLE crg_work.eqi_company
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LINES TERMINATED BY '\\n';

LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/local/apps/msadeploy/output/clarifi/ingestion/output/eqi_disagg_display.csv' INTO TABLE crg_work.eqi_disagg_display
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LINES TERMINATED BY '\\n';

LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/local/apps/msadeploy/output/clarifi/ingestion/output/eqi_period.csv' INTO TABLE crg_work.eqi_period
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LINES TERMINATED BY '\\n';

LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/local/apps/msadeploy/output/clarifi/ingestion/output/euro_company.csv' INTO TABLE crg_work.euro_company
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LINES TERMINATED BY '\\n';

LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/local/apps/msadeploy/output/clarifi/ingestion/output/euro_monthly.csv' INTO TABLE crg_work.euro_monthly
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LINES TERMINATED BY '\\n';

LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/local/apps/msadeploy/output/clarifi/ingestion/output/euro_monthly_deciles.csv' INTO TABLE crg_work.euro_monthly_deciles
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LINES TERMINATED BY '\\n';

LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/local/apps/msadeploy/output/clarifi/ingestion/output/euro_monthly_disagg.csv' INTO TABLE crg_work.euro_monthly_disagg
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LINES TERMINATED BY '\\n';

LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/local/apps/msadeploy/output/clarifi/ingestion/output/euro_period.csv' INTO TABLE crg_work.euro_period
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LINES TERMINATED BY '\\n';
"""

    try {
        mysqlSql.execute(crg_work_sync)

        mysqlSql.commit()

    } catch(ex) {
        println 'Error executing queries';
        throw ex
    } finally {
        mysqlSql.close()
    }
```

This is my groovy script, keep getting MySQL syntax errors, i have mysql java connector, version: '5.1.6'
here is the eror

Caused by: org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.dao.QueryException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/local/apps/msadeploy/output/clarifi/ingestion/output/eq' at line 5

Comment: Does it work if you do each line at a time instead of one big string of statements?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use multiple statements delimited by semicolons in this way.  Execute them one at a time instead.

Answer (score 0):

There were two issues:

1) Cannot have multi-line statements, needs to be in one line

2) Could not execute multiple queries, got "Packets out of order" error

Had to execute each query individually.